# Joining two tables without duplicating

Tags: sql, firebird

I have tables like this

Table 1 :

```
ID        NAME
001       John
```

Table 2 :

```
ID        NAME          FAMILY
001       John          Kate
001       John          Jane
```

Table 3 :

```
ID        NAME          TRAINING
001       John          ERP
001       John          CCNA
001       John          Java
```

I want to join these tables and show data like this :

Join Table :

```
ID        NAME         FAMILY          TRAINING
001       John         Kate            ERP
001       John         Jane            CCNA
001       John                         Java
```

Can someone help me find a SQL statement so that I can get that result?

I Try using UNION like this

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.name, table2.family, null as training
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID

UNION

SELECT table1.ID, table1.name, null as family, table3.training
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table3.ID
```

i got result like this :

```
ID        NAME         FAMILY          TRAINING
001       John         Kate            NULL
001       John         Jane            NULL
001       John         NULL            Java
001       John         NULL            CCNA
001       John         NULL            ERP
```

but, i want to got result like this

```
ID        NAME         FAMILY          TRAINING
001       John         Kate            ERP
001       John         Jane            CCNA
001       John         NULL            Java
```

so, anyone here can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why does the ID field always have a value of '001'? Is that really the case? If not can you fix it

Comment: What version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: thats for the example, i want to show data from a user like that.
i use firebird 2.5

Comment: why do you replicate the name¿?

Comment: the name is from master table, and it show a duplicate value because i join it with table 2 and table 3 wich is table family and table training.

Comment: How do you know which John did what training? All you got in the sample tables is 2 John's each with different family, and 3 John's who each had a different training. How do you know which John is which? Or is it one John, with 2 family members and 3 trainings? In that case the result you're looking for is weird; John with family Kate did ERP, John with family Jane did CCNA, John with no/unknown family did Java. This does not mean anything in real world terms.

Comment: John is same person, actually its 3 tables and john is on table 1. Table 2 is his familiy member, at this case, they are kate and jane, and john already got 3 trainingsm it's ERP, CCNA, and Java.

Comment: i know the result is weird, but what i want to do is using a lot of table, and i just to got result for minimum rows for one ID

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this can be done in a generic way. There is no way to connect Training to Family, there is no connection between the 2. Kate has nothing to do with ERP, could just as easily be CCNA or Java. Therefor, you will always get 6 results: John-Kate-3 Trainings, John-Jane-3 Trainings. (which is the correct result, logically speaking)
If you really want the result you mentioned, and I can't think of a reason why you would, you'd have to write a non-generic query. This would probably be along the lines of:
First select John, Kate and a (random?) training (top 1, or something, I'm not familiar with firebird)
Then select the same for Jane
Finally select John, NULL and the left-over training.

Like I said, this would be a non-generic query where you use the values "Kate" and "Jane" in the where clause(s).

If I where you, I'd have some deep thoughts about the whole set-up, and what you're trying to accomplish. You are trying to use SQL to do something it was never meant to do, in fact, it's the opposite of what SQL was meant to do.